# Convert image to 8 bits per pixel adaptive color BMP using ImageMagick

Tags: bitmap, imagemagick, image-conversion

The input image is color (not grayscale) but with very few colors (<16 colors).
The output image must be 8 bits per pixel (not 4 bit per pixel/not 8bit per color/not grayscale) BMP.
The converion must be lossless. (unless the colors more than 256)

What ImageMagick parameters should I use to achieve it ?

Thanks!

I have tried some parameters like:

```
-colors 256
-type Palette or optimize
-depth 8
```

But they all output a 4 bits per pixel BMP.
I want to ensure the output image a 8 bit per pixel BMP.

Any command-line solution other than ImageMagick is welcomed.

Comment: Any luck with my answer?

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest **NetPBM** and specifically its `ppmtobmp` tool. If we use a command of the following type to create a PPM file with any desired number of colours:

```
magick -size 64x64 xc: +noise random -colors 9 ppm: | ...
```

we can then examine what `ppmtobmp` does.

So firstly the default, which is to write the smallest possible image given the number of colours present (the same as what **ImageMagick** would do):

```
magick -size 64x64 xc: +noise random -colors 9 ppm: | ppmtobmp > result.bmp
ppmtobmp: analyzing colors...
ppmtobmp: 9 colors found
ppmtobmp: Writing 4 bits per pixel with a color palette
```

But if we specify `-bpp 8`, we get:

```
magick -size 64x64 xc: +noise random -colors 9 ppm: | ppmtobmp -bpp 8 > result.bmp
ppmtobmp: analyzing colors...
ppmtobmp: 9 colors found
ppmtobmp: Writing 8 bits per pixel with a color palette
```

And if we submit too many colours for a palette image, it aborts with a failed status ($?=1):

```
magick -size 64x64 xc: +noise random -colors 258 ppm: | ppmtobmp -bpp 8 > result.bmp
ppmtobmp: analyzing colors...
ppmtobmp: More than 256 colors found
ppmtobmp: There are too many colors in the image to represent in the number of bits per pixel you requested: 8.  You may use Pnmquant to reduce the number of colors in the image.
```