# How to save an 8-bit bmp with Julia

Tags: image, julia, bmp, 8-bit

I am trying to save 8-bit bmp files for use with a hardware device*.  I am using Julia.  Whatever I try, I am only able to get 24-bit bmp files.  Here is a minimal working example to illustrate the problem:

```
using Images, FileIO
dir = "/path/to/dir/"
img = n0f8.(Gray.(rand(100,100)))
save(dir * "image.bmp",img)
```

If I examine the properties of the resulting image, it is 24 bits.  The problem seems to be that, even though the image is grayscale, Julia saves it with three color channels.  Apparently 8-bit bmps use a different format, but it is unclear to me whether it is possible to save in this format using Julia.

**How can I save an 8-bit .bmp with Julia?**

---

*The hardware is a spatial light modulator, and the 8-bit .bmp format is non-negotiable.

Comment: If you don't get a Julia solution, you can maybe shell out to NetPBM and get the job done that way, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/76199430/2836621

Comment: I don't know about bmps, but `dir * "image.bmp"` results in `"/path/to/dirimage.bmp"`. It's much better to use `joinpath` when building file paths.

Comment: `im` is not the best name for a variable (it's the imaginary unit in julia) and you are saving another array in your example.

Comment: @ThomasJalabert Thanks, fixed.  I hastily copied from a notebook and modified the names to suit the context.  No excuses, though--my bad.

Comment: @DNF Thanks, fixed.  I copied from a notebook and changed some variables to suit this context, but made some errors.  No excuses, though--my bad.

Comment: @Yly I'm not really concerned about the typo, I just pointed it out since it shows why you shouldn't use `*` to build path strings.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like [Images.jl](https://juliaio.github.io/FileIO.jl/stable/registry/#Registry-table) does not support 8-bit .bmp but ".pgm" and ".png" allow 8-bit color depth.

Answer (score 1):

As it seems from @ThomasJalabert answer, Julia is unable to save an 8bpp (palette) BMP, you will probably need a work-around like I suggested in the comments using **NetPBM** which seems already to be used in `Images.jl` anyway.

So, as you would be using NetPBM to write the 8bpp BMP, you might as well save your image from Julia in NetPBM's native format which is `PGM` for grayscale images and `PPM` for colour images.

Assuming you can do that, and create `IMAGE.PPM` from Julia, you then need to execute the following command (which I presume you enclose in backticks in Julia) to create 8bpp `result.bmp`:

```
ppmtobmp -bpp 8 > result.bmp < IMAGE.PPM
```

I assume you have created an image with fewer than 256 colours already, but if not, you can use `pnmquant` in the command to reduce to 256 colours suitable for an 8bpp BMP like this:

```
pnmquant 256 < IMAGE.PPM | ppmtobmp -bpp 8 > result.bmp
```